# how to clear form elements inside table based on some conditions

Tags: jquery, jsf

I am having `rich:dataTable` inside that many div elements are defined. Each div element is having `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` and some number of input boxes. How to clear those input boxes only if checkbox is not checked. My sample code snippet

```
<rich:dataTable>
 <div id="#1">
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value=""/>
  <h:inputText value=""/>
  <h:inputText value=""/>
 </div>

 <div id="#2">
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value=""/>
  <h:inputText value=""/>      
 </div>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: The question sounds like a bad practice from a usability standpoint (See http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20000416.html , for example).  If the checkbox is not checked, **ignore** the value, do not clear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jQuery snippet should work for you, it will clear the values of all the text boxes if the checkbox next to them is unchecked within the same DIV.

```
       $("div :checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function () {
            $(this).siblings(":text").val("");
        });
```